# Refresh failed en Server Manager Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012

tengo el siguiente problema. 
La verdad es que no se nada de esto es el primer acercamiento que tengo, ya busque como solucionarlo con comandos en CMD

`for /f %s in (‘dir /b *.mof *.mfl’) do mofcomp %s`

pero no me resulta. Necesito migrar un proyecto, pero no se como hacerlo y tengo este problema:

[image: Estado del Server Manager con errores]

Comment: Agrega el error a la pregunta, va ser mas facil ayudarte

Comment: el problema es Refresh failed como dice la pregunta

Comment: Lo ejecutaste desde esta carpeta  `C:\Windows\System32\wbem\AutoRecover`

Comment: el manager desde el Desktop, la parte del comando **for /f %s in (‘dir /b *.mof *.mfl’) do mofcomp %s**  desde CMD @cacacho

Comment: prueba ejecutarlo desde ahi